# Joomla 2.5 HTML5 Template

Tags: html, joomla, joomla-template

I'm learning how to create a template in Joomla 2.5 and I have the following  code from the Lynda course I'm following:

```
<head>
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" >
<head>
<jdoc:include type="head" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/system/css/system.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/system/css/general.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/default.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

I want to use HTML5. Can I just swapout the xhtml 1.0 doc type above with the following (or i'm I missing anything else to include html5?):

```
<head>
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" >
<head>
<jdoc:include type="head" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/system/css/system.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/system/css/general.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/default.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Comment: You can swap it, only it won't validate id deprecated tags are used

Comment: you also won't be needing `type="text/css"` ;)

Answer (score 0):

For Joomla 3.2:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->setHtml5(true);
```

You can [see](http://www.newsroom.cz/joomla/81-joomla-english/129-how-to-set-the-head-section-of-joomla-3-2-to-html5.html)...